# Retry after delay if signal doesn't send next in ReactiveCocoa 4

Tags: swift, reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-4

I am using ReactiveCocoa 4.0 with Swift. I have a signal called `startedSignal` of type `Signal<String, NoError>` that I subscribe to in a view controller.

```
startedSignal.observeNext { _ in
  // Do stuff
}
```

I basically want to wait a number of seconds, then do something else if `startedSignal` doesn't send in any next values. I looked at the docs and saw things like `retry` on `SignalProducer` but I am not sure how that can be used to achieve this, given that `startedSignal` doesn't complete or send errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While `Rex` is useful if you have some more advanced use cases and you don't want to implement this logic yourself, you can actually do this with the existing operators in `ReactiveCocoa`, using a combination of `timeoutWithError` and `flatMapError` or `retry`:

```
signal
   .promoteErrors(Error.self)
   .timeoutWithError(
      .Timeout, 
      afterInterval: interval,
      onScheduler: QueueScheduler()
   )
   .flatMapError { error in
      return anotherProducer
   }

  // Somewhere else:
  private enum Error: ErrorType {
    case Timeout
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Exactly the kind of details I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I think [Rex's timeout](https://github.com/neilpa/Rex/blob/master/Source/Signal.swift#L53#L73) is what you want. It would look like this:

```
let alternative: Event<String, NoError> = ...

startedSignal.timeoutAfter(1.0, event: alternative, onScheduler: UIScheduler()).observeNext { _ in
  // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I get very disoriented when it comes to disposables, and I'm not sure about introducing a dependency just for one function. Would it be possible to use it standalone?

Comment: You could 1) use `timeoutWithError ` which belongs to RAC 2) extract the specific function from Rex.